# What actually happens on re-render?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, rerender, ajax

I would like to know what actually happens on re-render (Ajax Call and DOM replacement) in Salesforce.

My Idea:

1. The ajax call is made to get data.
2. On completion of the ajax call, the DOM is constructed(the new part).
3. The DOM Element is updated/replaced.

Is the DOM updated or replaced?

My Scenario :

I have a Visualforce Page which has multiple input items. I binds `keypress event` to the `input` elements on document ready. An action function is present which re-renders a section of the page.

Now, the input elements in the re-rendered panel do not have a `keypress event` binding.

However, when I have the `document.ready()` script in the re-rendered output panel, the `keypress event` gets binded.

Can someone explain how exactly re-render works?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When a re-render occurs, only the portion of the DOM that is set to rerender is actually re-rendered. Therefore, any jQuery event bindings that you created on **$(document).ready()** are essentially lost for the portion of the DOM that was re-rendered. If you wrap these event binding calls in a function, it's easy to re-bind.

What I do in these scenarios is use the **onComplete** attribute of something like a **commandLink** to call a function to "re-bind" my event handlers. Here is an example...

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!doSomething}" rerender="Something" onComplete="bindEvents();">
```

And then my bindEvents function and also my **$(document).ready()**...

```
function bindEvents() {
  $('#myElement').click(function() {
    // implemtation
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  bindEvents();
});
```

Comment: I understand the that DOM elements are not binded after re-rendering. But I'm trying to understand what actually happens on rerender. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Vignesh I explained exactly what happens on a re-render in the first paragraph of my response. Is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah! I get it. I was hoping if someone would explain me what re-render means(the DOM changes and stuff).

Comment: I want to help but I am still confused on what you are looking for. Re-render means partial DOM re-rendering. It simply re-renders only the elements that are specified to re-render...not the whole DOM. This happens after the AJAX callback is received. Is the whole jQuery.ready() thing throwing you off? The reason that works when inside the re-rendered element is because the DOM is already loaded so the callback happens immediately. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/D3cQ4/

Comment: Thanks! I totally understand about the jQuery.ready() part. I'm trying to get exact details of what re-render means and how the ajax requests are done with the auto-generated ids. That's it! Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

For this issue i use jQuery `live` function and don't care about DOM "updates":

```
<apex:inputText value="{!myVar}" id="myINput"/>

jQuery('[id$=myInput]').live('keypress', function(){
    ....
});
```

Comment: I understand .live() will fix the issue. I'm trying to understand what actually happens on re-render. Is there any documentation on what exactly happens? Btw, thanks for the help!

Comment: Just an FYI, jQuery.live() is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: jQuery.live() is replaced by jQuery.on() . @KevinO'Hara 's approach is better though.

Comment: I prefer the approach from @KevinO'Hara but it seems you can still use `.on()` as a replacement for `.live()` if you're using delegated event handlers: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events